# Adding a date column to a query result

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sum

I have the following table and want to add an extra column to the end.

running_data:

```
name      miles_ran     date
josh      1             2020-01-01
troy      2             2020-01-01
mark      1             2020-01-01
josh      1             2020-01-01
troy      1             2020-01-02
```

I want to group by person and see how many miles they ran on a certain date, so I came up with the following query.

```
SELECT name, SUM(miles_ran) FROM running_data WHERE date = '2020-01-01' GROUP BY name;
```

This query results in this:

```
name     miles_ran_sum
josh     2
troy     2
mark     1
```

However, I want to add a column at the end that says '2020-01-01' for all of the rows. How would I do that like this?

```
name     miles_ran_sum   date
josh     2               2020-01-01
troy     2               2020-01-01
mark     1               2020-01-01
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a column with a literal, fixed value to the `select` clause:

```
SELECT name, SUM(miles_ran) total_miles_ran, '2020-01-01' date
FROM running_data 
WHERE date = '2020-01-01' 
GROUP BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Analytic` function to get this data -

Since you need data only for a specific date, i have added one condition in SQL. you can please remove it if you opt to pull data for all dates.

```
Select distinct t.name, t.miles_ran_sum, t.date
```

from (SELECT name, SUM(miles_ran) over (partition by name, date order by name) miles_ran_sum, date
FROM running_data where date = '2020-01-01') t;

Alternate way -

```
select name, date, sum(miles_ran) as miles_ran_sum
from running_data where date = '2020-01-01'
group by name, date;
```